# Convert JS object with a list to C# list

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing, dynamic

My client is sending me a object like this:

```
"content": {
    "title": "data title",
    "values": {
        "25": "some description",
        "26": "some info",
        "27": "some text",
        "28": "some other data",
        "29": "more info",
        "30": "more text",
        "31": "and another more description"
    }
}
```

and I need to save the `values` on a C# `List<>` object.
I'm trying to get and save those values like this:

```
public static List<MyKeyValuePair> GetClientValues(dynamic content)
{
    var myList = new List<MyKeyValuePair>();

    try
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in content.values.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = "";
            myList.Add(new MyKeyValuePair() { Id = int.Parse(pi.Name), Description = pi.GetValue(value, null).ToString() });
        }
    }
    catch { }   

    return myList;
}
```

However on the `foreach` line I'm getting this error message:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.values' is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dynamic is already typed, you should be able to do the following:

```
public static List<MyKeyValuePair> GetClientValues(dynamic content)
{
    var myList = new List<MyKeyValuePair>();

    foreach (var kv in content["values"])
    {
        myList.Add(new MyKeyValuePair {
            Id = int.Parse(kv.Key),
            Description = kv.Value
        });
    }

    return myList;
}
```

Otherwise, you may need to deserialize the input json string.

Comment: Thanks @styfle! With that code I was getting the same error message as well but I change my `foreach` line to `foreach (var kv in content["values"])` and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio 2013 and greater you copy this json and generate a class out of it using the paste json as class under the edit menu, however if you are using a lower version of VS you can still type out the class structure and then the next step would be to use newtonsoft json to deserialise json into the class created above.